# Is there any way to call a void and return in the same line?

Tags: c, void

I'm working a project with the specific goal of minimizing the number of lines of my code, and I was wondering if you gurus had any knowledge about this!

I have a function that has to return a void*, and the last line in it calls a void function and then returns 0, like this:

```
void void_function(){
  //foo
}

void* my_function(){
  ...
  void_function();
  return 0;
}
```

Is there some sneaky way to call `void_function` and return 0 (or any other value) in the same line? Everything that I've tried has thrown errors, because C really doesn't seem to want me to mess with void functions.

EDIT:
To clarify, the goal here is the least total lines, where a line is defined as a semicolon. Obviously this isn't production code, it's just for fun!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you are trying to do

Comment: is your aim to reduce number of lines or to understand how a void * function works?

Comment: why tag C++ when you're asking about C?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand why you would want something like this ? You could just use -O3 and let compiler do whatever it needs to. I don't see any gains here.

Comment: Do you want less lines or less code?   
Why you want to make your application less readable?
You can shorten your whole program to one line if you like.  It would  be very hard to read.  But if that's what you want...

Answer (score 8):

There's always the comma operator, although it doesn't make the code any more readable

```
return void_function(), 0;
```

Comment: I don't think it has reduced anything. It can be thought as replacing semi-colon with a comma. You can always have multiple expressions in the same line. Nothing much gained here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always (ab)use preprocessor macros:

```
#define CALL_AND_RETURN(x) {x; return 0;}

[...]

CALL_AND_RETURN(void_function());
```

I don't think this is a good idea, though, since it doesn't gain you much and it makes your code harder for other people to understand.

Comment: I think you just shifted the lines above and not reduce it. It would have been helpful if there were multiple such calls.

Comment: Yes, of course; I assumed that the questioner's actual code has multiple such functions (otherwise why would he care about minimizing code length?), and that he only listed one for the sake of brevity.

Comment: But this makes no difference, the preprocessed code will be identical to the original code in the question

Comment: @user16217248 it makes no difference to the compiler; it might make a difference the human being who is writing or reading the code.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner What if OP is trying to achieve calling a void function in line, and their is no otherway besides the comma operator to do that

Answer (score 0):

Create a lambda that calls void_function() and returns 0, then from the my_function() you can return that invoked lambda.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more ? Looks like a comment

Comment: C doesn't have lambdas.

Comment: This post was marked as C++ when my post was made.  It was subsequently edited. Thanks